# PC connection whopping from mouse to mouse randomly

Tags: wireless-mouse

There are several PCs at home with wireless Tecknet mice, randomly the PC I work with pairs with a different mouse, How can I stop this whopping?

PCs run windows 10, mice are Tecknet M002

Comment: Evidently the wireless dongles for them in the PC's are too close to each other. Move the PC's further away or use different manufacturers for wireless mice.

Comment: The definition of "whopping" I'm familiar with means very large.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like several of your mice are getting paired to the same device. Open your device driver software (or if you haven't downloaded it yet, go ahead and download it from [here](http://www.tecknet.co.uk/support/m002-red.html)). Go to the connection settings, and un-pair any mice you are not trying to use. If that doesn't work, got to your PC's Bluetooth settings and remove any unwanted pairings. Between those two methods, you should be able to solve your issue.